# visualize a two-dimensional point set using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, visualization

I'm new to Python and want to perform a rather simple task. I've got a two-dimensional point set, which is stored as binary data (i.e. `(x, y)`-coordinates) in a file, which I want to visualize. The output should look as in the picture below.

However, I'm somehow overwhelmed by the amount of google results on this topic. And many of them seem to be for three-dimensional point cloud visualization and/or a massive amount of data points. So, if anyone could point me to a suitable solution for my problem, I would be really thankful.

[image: pointset]

**EDIT**: The point set is contained in a file which is formatted as follows:

```
0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000
1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000
1
0.020375738732779   0.026169010160356
0.050815740313746   0.023209931647163
0.072530406907906   0.023975230642589
```

The first data vector is the one in the line below the single "1"; i.e. `(0.020375738732779, 0.026169010160356)`. How do I read this into a vector in python? I can open the file using `f = open("pointset file")`

Comment: - Do you want the output to look more or less _exactly_ as it does in the sample image?
- Do you want the points to be plotted to an image/graph that is proportioned such that the points will be plotted preserving the aspect ratio of the space they occupy? Or do you not mind if the aspect ratio is skewed to fit a viewport/window of given ratio..?

Comment: How is your data in the file formatted? You say in the question that it is formatted in binary, but your sample appears to show data in plaintext. Which is it?

Comment: This question can be decomposed into 3 sub-questions: 1) how to find specific line in a file 2) how to load text file data in python and 3) how to display a scatter plot. All of these answers exist in SO if you query for them. For 1, use `open(f, "r").readlines()`, and search for the line number corresponding to the line that equals "1\n" . For 2), use [numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) with the `skiprows` argument deduced from 1) . For 3) , I suggest [matplotlib.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

Answer (score 7):

Install and import matplotlib and pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Assuming this is your data:

```
x = [1, 2, 5, 1, 5, 7, 8, 3, 2, 6]
y = [6, 7, 1, 2, 6, 2, 1, 6, 3, 1]
```

If you need, you can use a comprehension to split the coordinates into seperate lists:

```
x = [p[0] for p in points]
y = [p[1] for p in points]
```

Plotting is as simple as:

```
plt.scatter(x=x, y=y)
```

Result:

[image: Scatter Plot]

Many customizations are possible.

**EDIT:** following question edit

In order to read the file:

```
x = []
y = []
with open('pointset_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        coords = line.split(' ')
        x.append(float(coords[0]))
        y.append(float(coords[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The vectors are contained in a file which is formatted as I edited in the question? Could you tell me how I can read the vectors into vectors in python?

Comment: with open("data.txt") as fid:
       lines = fid.read().split("\n")
   data = [[float(d) for d in line.split(" ") if d] for line in lines[3:]]
   
   plt.scatter(data[0], data[1])

Comment: Maybe it is because I'm running the code in Python Application created by Visual Studio, but the window with the plot, which is opened after the `plt.scatter(x=x, y=y)` line immediately closes ...

Comment: Oh, and in your code above, `x.append(float(coords[0]))` also adds `float(coords[0])` to `y`; not only to `x`. I'm not familiar with python, but I guess `x` is a reference to the same object as `y` is referring to. If I replace `x = y = []` by `x = []` and `y = []`, then everything works as expected.

Comment: Fixed. Interesting, I'll look into that. Thanks.

Comment: This difference is to do with list pointers. `x=y=[]` only makes one list in memory that both variables reference. Appending to `x` and then reading from `y` will show the same change in memory.
Many people use Jupyter with matplotlib, so they do not deal with the window immediately closing, but you should add a line `input()` to the end of your program so that it pauses with the window open.
Please accept Omri's answer if it is helpful.

Comment: @0xbadf00d if your window immediately closes you can try `plt.show()` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could read your data as follow, and plot using scattr plot. this method is considering for small number of data and not csv, just the format you have presented.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open("pointset file") as fid:
   lines = fid.read().split("\n")

# lines[:2] looks like the bounds for each axis, if yes use it in plot 
data = [[float(d) for d in line.split(" ") if d] for line in lines[3:]]   
plt.scatter(data[0], data[1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a plot looking pretty much exactly like the sample image you give, and you want the plot to display the data with both axes in equal proportion, one could use a general purpose multimedia library like pygame to achieve this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import pygame

# windows will never be larger than this in their largest dimension
MAX_WINDOW_SIZE = 400
BG_COLOUR = (255, 255, 255,)
FG_COLOUR = (0, 0, 0,)
DATA_POINT_SIZE = 2

pygame.init()

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Error: need filename to read data from')
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    data_points = []
    # read in data points from file first
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
        [next(file) for _ in range(3)]  # discard first 3 lines of file
        # now the rest of the file contains actual data to process
        data_points.extend(tuple(float(x) for x in line.split()) for line in file)
    # file read complete. now let's find the min and max bounds of the data
    top_left = [float('+Inf'), float('+Inf')]
    bottom_right = [float('-Inf'), float('-Inf')]
    for datum in data_points:
        if datum[0] < top_left[0]:
            top_left[0] = datum[0]
        if datum[1] < top_left[1]:
            top_left[1] = datum[1]
        if datum[0] > bottom_right[0]:
            bottom_right[0] = datum[0]
        if datum[1] > bottom_right[1]:
            bottom_right[1] = datum[1]
    # calculate space dimensions
    space_dimensions = (bottom_right[0] - top_left[0], bottom_right[1] - top_left[1])
    # take the biggest of the X or Y dimensions of the point space and scale it
    # up to our maximum window size
    biggest = max(space_dimensions)
    scale_factor = MAX_WINDOW_SIZE / biggest  # all points will be scaled up by this factor
    # screen dimensions
    screen_dimensions = tuple(sd * scale_factor for sd in space_dimensions)
    # basic init and draw all points to screen
    display = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_dimensions)
    display.fill(BG_COLOUR)
    for point in data_points:
        # translate and scale each point
        x = point[0] * scale_factor - top_left[0] * scale_factor
        y = point[1] * scale_factor - top_left[1] * scale_factor
        pygame.draw.circle(display, FG_COLOUR, (x, y), DATA_POINT_SIZE)
    pygame.display.update()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
        pygame.time.wait(50)
```

Execute this script and pass the name of the file which holds your data in as the first argument. It will spawn a window with the data points displayed.

I generated a bunch of uniformly distributed random x,y points to test it, with:

```py
from random import random

for _ in range(1000):
    print(random(), random())
```

This produces a window looking like the following:

[image]

If the space your data points are within is not of square size, the window shape will change to reflect this. The largest dimension of the window, either width or height, will always stay at a specified size (I used 400px as a default in my demo).

Admittedly, this is not the most elegant or concise solution, and reinvents the wheel a little bit, however it gives you the most control on how to display your data points, and it also deals with both the reading in of the file data and the display of it.

Answer (score 0):

To read your file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('your_file',
                 sep='\s+', 
                 header=None,
                 skiprows=3,
                 names=['x','y'])
```

For now I've created a random dataset

```
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[random.uniform(0, 1) for n in range(100)],
                   'y':[random.uniform(0, 1) for n in range(100)]})
```

I prefer Plotly for any kind of figure

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(df,
                 x='x',
                 y='y')
fig.show()
```

[image: fig]

From here you can easily update labels, colors, etc.